# Tensorflow: gradients are zero for LSTM and GradientDescentOptimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Gradients which are computed by GradientDescentOptimizer for LSTM network are always zero. They are zero even on the first step, so, I think it is not vanishing gradient problem. The same issue happens for AdamOptimizer.

I have reduced input to one point of time series and label (expected output) to just next point with additional information for neural network to predict in hope to find the root cause on why gradients are zeros. Gradients are zeros even in this minimal setup.

I have read similar question but have not answer which could help me.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

def input_placeholder_sequence(input_placeholder, sequence_length, batch_size):
    input_placeholder = tf.transpose(input_placeholder, name="transpose_input")

    print("input_placeholder shape: " + str(input_placeholder.get_shape()))

    input_placeholder = tf.split(input_placeholder, np.repeat(batch_size, sequence_length), axis=0)

    print("input_placeholder_sequence shape: " + str(np.shape(input_placeholder)))
    print("input_placeholder_in_sequence shape: " + str(input_placeholder[0].get_shape()))

    return input_placeholder

def train_model(input_placeholder, sequence_length, batch_size, output_size):
    input_placeholder = input_placeholder_sequence(input_placeholder, sequence_length, batch_size)
    rnn_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(output_size, name="hidden_layer")

    hidden_outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cell, input_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)

    print("hidden_outputs shape: " + str(np.shape(hidden_outputs)))
    print("hidden_outputs last shape: " + str(hidden_outputs[-1].get_shape()))

    result = tf.concat(hidden_outputs, 0, name="concat")

    print("result shape: " + str(result.get_shape()))

    result = tf.transpose(result, name="transpose_result")

    print("result shape transposed: " + str(result.get_shape()))

    return result, rnn_cell, states

def main():
    input = [[1448949600], [3], [0.70089], [0.70089], [0.70086], [0.70089], [0.70071], [0.70071], [0.7007], [0.70071]]
    label = [[1448949660], [10], [0.70086], [0.7009], [0.70084], [0.70092], [0.7007], [0.70071], [0.70067], [0.70073], [0], [0], [0], [1]]

    print("input shape: " + str(np.shape(input)))
    print("label shape: " + str(np.shape(label)))

    input_size = np.shape(input)[0]
    output_size = np.shape(label)[0]
    batch_size = 1
    sequence_length = 1
    learning_rate = 0.01

    print("input_size: " + str(input_size))
    print("output_size: " + str(output_size))
    print("batch_size: " + str(batch_size))
    print("sequence_length: " + str(sequence_length))

    input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (input_size, sequence_length * batch_size), "input")

    prediction_operation, rnn_cell, states = train_model(input_placeholder, sequence_length, batch_size, output_size)

    label_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (output_size, batch_size), "label")

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step',trainable=False)

    cost = tf.norm(tf.subtract(prediction_operation, label_placeholder))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
    minimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients, global_step)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(init)

        _, prediction, loss, grads, weights, gl_step \
            = session.run([minimizer, prediction_operation, cost, gradients, rnn_cell.weights, global_step],
                          feed_dict={input_placeholder: input, label_placeholder: label})
        print("loss: " + str(loss))
        print("prediction: " + str(prediction))

        print("rnn weights and biases: " + str(weights))
        print("rnn weights and biases shape: " + str(np.shape(weights)))
        print("rnn weights shape: " + str(np.shape(weights[0])))
        print("rnn biases shape: " + str(np.shape(weights[1])))

        print("rnn weights and biases sum: " + str(np.sum(np.abs(weights[0])) + np.sum(np.abs(weights[1]))))

        print("gradients and variables: " + str(grads))
        print("gradients weights: " + str(grads[0][0]))
        print("gradients biases: " + str(grads[1][0]))
        print("gradients sum: " + str(np.sum(np.abs(grads[0][0])) + np.sum(np.abs(grads[1][0]))))

        print("global steps: " + str(gl_step))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you try using tfdbg to see where zeros appear in your network?

Comment: I checked in tfdbg. Biases and states of BasicLSTMCell are zeros, but it is expected, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation is correct. Input and label results into vanishing gradients.

If input and label are as follows, gradients are not zeros.

```
input = [[3], [0.70089], [0.70089], [0.70086], [0.70089], [0.70071], [0.70071], [0.7007], [0.70071]]
label = [[10], [0.70086], [0.7009], [0.70084], [0.70092], [0.7007], [0.70071], [0.70067], [0.70073], [0], [0], [0], [1]]
```